# Using setInterval with asynch functions that could take longer than the interval time

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to keep your asynch functions somewhat in order using setInterval? For instance, if you're doing some kind of IO connection and it takes longer than the interval time you set you get things a little off. I could increase the interval time to something that hopefully would cover it, but that's not sure fire enough.

The code looks like this:

```
var sqlID = setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Attempting to reconnect to sql...');
    dbHandler.connectSQL(sql, connStr, function(sqlconnect){
        conn = sqlconnect;
        if (conn != false){
            clearInterval(sqlID);
        }
    });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Well async function are... async which mean they will execute aside of the execution runtime and return are not something when done. What you want to achieve is kind of against what async function do.

Comment: Right, but I was just wondering if there was a way to sort of manage them I guess. Maybe a queue or something.

Comment: You can use Promises/Deferreds

Comment: As above Promises/Deferreds are the way to go, though saying that, the 3rd argument your passing is a a success callback, why not rely on that?

Comment: use a wrapper function to re-call the function with a setTimeout each time. that way, you can re-schedule, re-interval, cancel, delay, etc, without any flow handling whatsoever.

Comment: There is a reconnect example on the node-mysql github page, depending on the sql lib you are using, it might give you a good example on how to reconnect after disconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them queued, wihtout Promises/Deferreds you can do:

```
function tryToConnectIn10Seconds(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     console.log('Attempting to reconnect to sql...');
     dbHandler.connectSQL(sql, connStr, function(sqlconnect){
        conn = sqlconnect;
        if (conn != false){
            //Done. Do something with conn
        }else{
            tryToConnectIn10Seconds();
        }
     });
   }, 10000);
}
```

Cheers